# Jquery loop creating same objects repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a loop to fill options to select2. Im getting data from backend and auto fill it when page is loaded if i have selected parameter in my url. So im creating 2 loops for it. But its generating options multiple times. It creates the options (DOM) as the same length of my array which i created an array from my parameters in url. Thanks for helps.

```
var myArr = urlProjects.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    myArr.forEach(e => {
        if (parseInt(e) === data.data[i].id) {
            var option = new Option(data.data[i].name, data.data[i].id, false, true);
            element.select2().append(option);
            projectsArr.push(data.data[i].id);
        } else {
            var option = new Option(data.data[i].name, data.data[i].id, false, false);
            element.select2().append(option);
        }
    })
}

urlProjects (example) = 12877,12618,10925

data.data (array of objects- example object) = {
    "id": 12573,
    "name": "TEST",
    "clientID": 1119,
    "rsid": "23bdb244-c92b-42d6-bc58-3282edf27d08",
    "clientName": "test",
    "clients": {
        "client_id": 1119,
        "name": "test",
        "opClientName": "[test]"
    }
}
```

Comment: what is in urlProjects and data.data (example data)?

Comment: Did you check how often your code is executed? Maybe you should remove all options before your code to make sure you never have double entries

Comment: You certainly have some other related code and call this piece of code you provided in some listener. What is `element.select2()`? Some library usage? What is `projectsArr`?

Comment: It's your else statement in the foreach loop. If  you don't have a match between data and myArr it places an element regardless. myArr is being looped through for every data element, so you'll have data.length * myArr.length number of elements

Comment: Thanks @Phaelaxz that else was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you always appending options, but instead you should re-fill array.

So, try to adjust your code as following:

```
var myArr = urlProjects.split(",");

element.select2() = element.select2(); // Don't have a clue what element.select2() does, from code it looks like it returns an array - so you have to adjust this part. Idea is to empty the array of your option elements.
projectsArr = []; // More-less same here.

// And then - actually, re-fill your arrays again.
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    myArr.forEach(e => {
        if (parseInt(e) === data.data[i].id) {
            var option = new Option(data.data[i].name, data.data[i].id, false, true);
            element.select2().append(option);
            projectsArr.push(data.data[i].id);
        } else {
            var option = new Option(data.data[i].name, data.data[i].id, false, false);
            element.select2().append(option);
        }
    })
}
```

There're some more optimal ways of doing it - checking whether your array already contains some elements and then only pushing new elements and/or updating existing ones.